# Angular2 - Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for 'App'(?, ?, ?)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am running my Angular2/Ionic2 app under Android 4.4.4 on a real device; however, I am getting a white black screen, after inspecting the device I got the following error:

**Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for 'App'(?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'App' is decorated with Injectable.**

*I've tried to run it on Android 5.1, it worked fine!*

I've read some posts saying that in order to hide the error, I should use crosswalk, but I believe that Ionic2 support Android versions >= 4.4.4 So it should work without crosswalk!

My index.html:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Ionic</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <link ios-href="build/css/app.ios.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link md-href="build/css/app.md.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link wp-href="build/css/app.wp.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ion-app></ion-app>
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.4/moment-timezone.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Zone.js and Reflect-metadata  -->
  <script src="build/js/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="build/js/Reflect.js"></script>
  <!-- the bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
  <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- Polyfill needed for platforms without Promise and Collection support -->
 <script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
export class MyApp {

static get parameters() {
return [[Platform], [MenuController],[Http], [TranslateService]];
}

constructor(platform, menu, http, translate) {

this.menu = menu;
this.platform = platform;
this.http=http;
this.translate = translate;

this.guestViewBool = localStorage.getItem('guestView');

platform.ready().then(() => {


   });
 }}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [], {
 iconMode: 'ios',
  backButtonIcon: 'ios-arrow-back',
 prodMode:'true',
});
```

Comment: Please show the code for `App()` and `@NgModule()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added App(); however, I've not an `@NgModule()` as natively that's not included in Ionic2

Comment: Sorry, don't know Ionic.

Comment: Why is the class in the error named `App`, the class added in your question `MyApp`? Also the number of parameters doesn't match. Perhaps another special case from Ionic I don't know about.

Comment: That's the thing, the error is class in the error is named `App` and in my code is `MyApp` I don't have an idea from where it came, you should know also that the error raises only on Android < 5.0

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Maybe someone else.

Comment: Also, the error is coming from a file named: `reflective_provider.js`

Comment: @HamzaL. I guess you should provide what dependency you are using in 2nd parameter of `ionicBootstrap` function instead of `[]` blank array(it should be list of providers),

Comment: @PankajParkar I don't use any dependencies...

Comment: @HamzaL. you have to inject `HTTP_PROVIDER` & `TranslateService` providers there in array(not really sure with ionic stuff)

Comment: @PankajParkar in Ionic2 you don't need to inject manually, it already working without it. What blows the mind is that the issue appears only on Android < 5.0!